# Programa de C++ de promedios de 5 calificaciones tiene como resultado 0.000

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un problema.

En un programa de C que sirve para sacar el promedio de cinco calificaciones, al correrlo, me sale como resultado 0.000

Todas las variables están declaradas correctamente, además el compilador no me salta ningún error ni advertencia. Uso Dev C++. Les adjunto el código fuente:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 using namespace std;
 main () 
 {
     int cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, cal5;
     float prom;
     printf ("Ingrese la primera calificacion:");
     scanf ("%d", & cal1);
     printf ("Ingrese la segunda calificacion:");
     scanf ("%d", & cal2);
     printf ("Ingrese la tercera calificacion:");
     scanf ("%d", & cal3);
     printf ("Ingrese la cuarta calificacion:");
     scanf ("%d", &cal4);
     printf ("Ingrese la quinta calificacion:");
     scanf ("%d", &cal5);
     prom = (cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4 + cal5)/5;
     printf ("El promedio es: %f", & prom);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Eso es porque tienes una division de enteros, por ende te da un entero, que luego se convierte a coma flotante. Cambia  `(cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4 + cal5)/5` por `(cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4 + cal5)/5.0`.

Comment: @EduenSarceño 48 dividido entre 5 no da un número entre 0 y 1.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ¿quién dijo que daba un número entre 0 y 1? Lo que quise decir que 48/5 dará como resultado 9, que luego se convertirá en 9.f

Comment: Efectivamente, dará como resultado 9, y 9 no es 0, que es el resultado que está obteniendo el autor de la pregunta (y que es un valor que sólo es obtenible si la división resulta en un número entre 0 y 1).

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos errores básicamente:

**Una división de enteros no genera decimales**

```
int cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, cal5;
float prom = (cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4 + cal5) / 5;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~
                          int                     int
```

Por mucho que `prom` sea `float`, la división es `int / int`, y esta división genera un resultado de tipo `int` (es decir, no tiene decimales), que posteriormente se recalcula a `float`. El problema de la conversión a `float` es que el resultado original ya ha perdido los decimales, luego `prom` tendrá problemas de precisión.

Este problema es sencillo de solucionar. Basta con hacer que uno de los dos términos de la operación sea de tipo `float`

```
float prom = (cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4 + cal5) / 5.f;
```

De esta forma, el procesador realizará la operación `float / float`, operación que sí que generará decimales.

**printf no necesita referencias**

```
printf ("El promedio es: %f", & prom);
```

`scanf` necesita referencias a las variables porque para su correcto funcionamiento tiene que modificar dichas variables. `printf`, en cambio, no necesita modificar nada, luego le basta con recibir una copia de los valores a mostrar.

El uso correcto de `printf`sería:

```
printf ("El promedio es: %f", prom);
```

En cualquier caso, estás programando en C++, así que sería más correcto y seguro usar los mecanismos de entrada/salida propios de C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Ingrese la primera calificacion:";
    std::cin >> cal1;
    std::cout << "Ingrese la segunda calificacion:";
    std::cin >> cal2;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: el eterno error....

Comment: @RaulLuna los eternos errores más bien XD

Comment: Si, pero le doy todas las calificaciones de 10, lo cual sería un promedio de 10 y me sigue saliendo 0, además, la corrección de printf no es la misma?

Comment: @Axel error mio, no le quité el &. Ya está corregido

Answer (score 0):

incorrecto :   printf ("El promedio es: %f", & prom);

Corrrecto:    printf ("El promedio es: %f", prom); no necesita referencia , si tiene muchos decimales le puedes poner  %.2f o dependiendo cuantos decimales quieras le cambias el numero